# Is there a similar server like Bitcoin core that truly supports accounts?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, bitcoin-core-accounts

Is there a similar server like Bitcoin core that truly supports accounts (and also RPC)?

I was hoping for something like the ethereum `geth` node. where each account has it's address and individually password protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin Core since 0.15 supports multiwallet.

That is probably much closer to what people expected the accounts feature to be (and confusion about it is one of the reasons for deprecating it).

Using multiwallet, one Bitcoin Core instance can maintain multiple entirely separated wallets simultaneously. They all have their own addresses, own keys, own transactions, own coins, own labels.

This is in contrast to the older accounts feature, where the keys, coins, and labels are shared across all accounts - only a balance was maintained per account.

Comment: This is very new and suprising to me! I was lead to think every instance can handle a single wallet with the '-wallet' switch. Can you please give RPC exaple on how to query a specific wallet for getbalance for example or other commands without restarting the deamon? Im on 0.15.1

Comment: Read more here: https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.15.0#multi-wallet-support

Comment: Thanks, the *big* problem with this new feature is that I can't create new wallets via RPC. seems like I need some hack/workaround  to (somehow) create a new empty `wallet-xxx.dat`, write a new `wallet` entry in the `bitcoin.conf` file, and *restart* Bitcoin Core. Am I right?

Comment: please see my related question: [RPC call to re-read config file?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70383/rpc-call-to-re-read-config-file)

Comment: That doesn't exist. For now, you'll need to restart if you want to add or remove wallets. The ability to change the wallets at runtime is being worked on for a later release.

Comment: Is there currently a limit to how many wallets I can load?